# How to cache html templates for SPA

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm making Single Page Application and I need to `prove a concept` that I can cache html templates into browser cache and reuse it later on.

I have dynamically generated html coming from php, it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#content').load('https://mysite.net.au/index.php?endpoint=get-html-template&template=FirstTemplate&version=1');               
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body id="content"></body>
</html>
```

I want to juggle with the urls in this file making it load specific template, utilizing browser cache.

If I need to update page template, I would chenge version to 2 or 3 and then it will reload template. To I practically need the html files to be cached forever.

This is in theory.

On practice, in Google chrome on the network page of developer tools I see

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js SIZE (from memory cache)  

index.php?endpoint=get-html-template&template=FirstTemplate&version=1  SIZE 2.2KB
```

So I conclude that html is not being loaded from cache.

I tried different `Response headers`

my last set looks like this:

```
Cache-control:max-age=31536000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1721
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 29 Jan 2018 00:56:01 GMT
ETag:"c9c67b-f9f0f-56393377f8681"
Expires:Tue, 29 Jan 2019 00:56:01 +0000
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Mon, 29 Jan 2018 00:27:57 +0000
Server:Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2l DAV/2 PHP/5.6.30
status:200
Vary:Accept-Encoding
x-cache:HIT
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.30
```

Is there something I don't take to account? I use Chrome 63 for Mac OS.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My urls are like this /api/load_angular_template/login?v=1. Any one got any clue how to cache these XHR requests

Comment: I wrote my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to effectively make any browser cache html. But they all cache JS files. So I'm here reinventing React JSX :)

Read more in es6 specification: [8.3.7 React JSX via tagged templates](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#_react-jsx-via-tagged-templates)

Basically es6 got a Web templates now and more.

It was yesterday when php generated html pages, today php generates javascript files.